# CondaValueError: could not parse | conda create -n myenv --file package-list.txt

Tags: anaconda, conda, python-venv, miniconda, anaconda3

Following this [conda docs tutorial](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands/list.html#Output,%20Prompt,%20and%20Flow%20Control%20Options); I created a `package-list.txt` of a conda venv I want to copy.

I tried:

```
$ conda create -n myenv --file package-list.txt

CondaValueError: could not parse 'absl-py                   0.15.0                   pypi_0    pypi' in: yasmine.txt
```

```
$ conda env create --file yasmine.txt -n yasmine

CondaValueError: invalid package specification: backcall                  0.2.0              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
```

**How do I install from this file in a new venv?**

I want to use this text file format.

---

`package-list.txt`:

```
env_
# packages in environment at C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\envs\fastai:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
absl-py                   0.15.0                   pypi_0    pypi
astunparse                1.6.3                    pypi_0    pypi
backcall                  0.2.0              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not the `conda list --export` format. Also, if you have PyPI packages in the environment, only `conda env export` supports those. So, try again with

```bash
conda env export -n fastai > fastai.yaml
conda env create -n myenv -f fastai.yaml
```